# Vuejs show/hide condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Adding and removing dynamic items is functioning.  I'm wanting to additionally show/hide elements under each.  However, when I "show/hide" it toggles all.  How can I call only the current index (toggle method?)

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    inputProject: [],
    counter:0,
    active : false
    },
    methods: {
    addInput: function() {
            this.inputProject.push(this.counter);
            this.counter++
        },
    removeInput: function(index) {
            this.inputProject.splice(index,1);
        },
    toggle: function (index) {
      this.active = !this.active;
    }
    }
})
```

[image]

Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rhgz83e2/30/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you change `active` property and it is `reflected` for all elements.

The solution is to assign `active` property for every object and use `v-show` directive.

```
 <p v-show="elem.active" v-bind:id="elem.id">show {{push}}</p>
```

[working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/rhgz83e2/39/)

```
var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     inputProject: [],
     counter:0
   },
   methods: {
      addInput: function() {
        this.inputProject.push({id:this.counter,active:false});
        console.log(this.inputProject);
        this.counter++
      },
      removeInput: function(index) {
        this.inputProject.splice(index,1);
      },
      toggle: function (index) {
        var item= this.inputProject.filter(a=>a.id==index)[0];
        item.active=!item.active;
      }
   }
})
```